# VBA. "Type mismatch: array or user-defined type expected"

Tags: vba, excel

I am completely new to VBA. I need to write a program, which will generate an array of integer and will find an index of the minimal element. I got this error 
"Type mismatch: array or user-defined type expected." I looked into many similar questions, but couldn't figure out what is wrong.

```
Function random_integer(Min As Integer, Max As Integer)
random_integer = Int((Max - Min + 1) * Rnd + Min)
End Function

Function generate_array(Size As Integer)
Dim Arr(Size)
For i = 0 To UBound(Arr)
    Arr(i) = random_integer(i - 10, i + 10)
Next
generate_array = Arr
End Function

Function find_index_of_min_elem(ByRef Arr() As Variant)
Dim Min As Integer
Min = Arr(0)
Dim MinIndex As Integer
MinIndex = 0
For i = 1 To UBound(Arr)
    If Arr(i) < Min Then
        Min = Arr(i)
        MinIndex = i
    End If
Next
find_index_of_min_elem = MinIndex
End Function

Sub task6()
A = generate_array(20)
IndexOfMinElemInA = find_index_of_min_elem(A)
MsgBox IndexOfMinElemInA
End Sub
```

Comment: `I am completely new to VBA....` Did you write this code?

Comment: Yes. I have experience in other languages

Comment: You'll want to drop the `snake_case` and adopt `PascalCase` for member names. In VBA the underscore has a special meaning; your functions can't be refactored into an interface named like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is the function `Function find_index_of_min_elem(ByRef Arr() As Integer)` is expecting an `Integer` as a parameter and you are passing `a` as a `Variant`

```
a = generate_array(20)
IndexOfMinElemInA = find_index_of_min_elem(a)
```

The next error that you will get is on `Dim Arr(Size) As Integer`. You cannot dimension an array like that.

I would recommend reading up on arrays.

There may be other errors but I have not checked those.

Comment: Congrats on reaching that 100K! Have another!

Comment: Thank you guys :)

Comment: I believe you might be eligible for a little something from the Stack Overflow team. Congrats!

Comment: Thanks @Mat'sMug but I seriously doubt that... :D

Comment: [I seriously think so =)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321681/1188513) - "Assuming you have a valid email address on your profile and you are opted in to receiving emails from us, you should get an automated email within a week of hitting the reputation threshold. If not, check your spam folder and make sure it didn't end up there."

Comment: News Alert! SO Mug up on eBay!

Comment: @Mat'sMug: Aha! That's news to me... yeah SO has the correct email.

Comment: Congrats again - next stop 250K!

Comment: @SiddharthRout still get same error. For some reason, excel shows that error in Sub task6()

Comment: You didn't have to make so many changes. You could have declared `a` in `Sub task6`  as `Dim a() as Integer`

Comment: @Jeeped: I can see you are going to reach there pretty soon :D

Comment: Late into the party!  congratulations :)

Comment: @Mat'sMug: Received the "You are Killing it!" email :)

Comment: @Mat'sMug : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321681/do-users-still-get-the-package-when-their-rep-reaches-100k/352173#352173

Comment: Nice! Congrats again!

Comment: @Mat'sMug: The only reason why I am updating you is because you were the one who made me aware of it :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

What about this? Make a second column of index numbers (in sequence from small to large) and then order the two rows by your original column. I've included the example below to illustrate:
A = the original column of numbers,
B = the column of index numbers
D & E are the result of sorting A & B by column A 
The answer is then: the lowest number "0" was at index 7

[image: example screenshot]